# How to use network frameworks (volley , okhttp , etc) in libgdx?

Tags: android, libgdx, android-volley, okhttp

I want to load some data from web using volley or okhttp in libgdx. 
How to use network frameworks like volley or okhttp in libgdx instead of [libgdx networking class](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Networking) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to add this `compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.3.0'` to your project `build.gradle` file for example

```
project(":core") {
    apply plugin: "java"


    dependencies {
            ...
            compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.3.0'
        }
    }
```

Then you can use okhttp in your core project here is an example :

```
public class OkhttpTest extends ApplicationAdapter {
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

    @Override
    public void create() {
        try {
            System.out.println(run("http://google.com"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    String run(String url) throws IOException {
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(url)
                .build();

        Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
        return response.body().string();
    }
}
```